# How to make an array of certain size in Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift

How do I make a simple array of say 1000 floats? I have tried this:

```
var computeArray = Array<Float>(repeating: nil, count:1000)
```

and get

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I also tried this and got the same thing:

```
var computeArray = [Float](repeating: nil, count:1000)
```

It's so simple but I can't get it to work. These are basically the same as examples I've found online.  Has something changed with the most recent Swift 4?

Comment: How do you expect it to put `nil` into an array of `Float`? Your `repeating:` value is wrong.

Comment: This happens because `nil` is not a valid value for a non-optional `Float`. Use `0` or some other initial value.

Comment: `var computeArray = [Float](repeating: 0, count: 1000)`. Or, if you're just trying to reserve capacity for 1000 floats, `var computeArray = [Float](); computeArray.reserveCapacity(1000)`. It depends upon what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's pretty simple if you respect Swift's strong type system ;) A `nil` value in an non-optional container is against the rules.

Comment: By the way, your syntax would not have worked in Swift 3, either.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this.

```
var computeArray: Array<Float> = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1000)
```

or with nils

```
var computeArray: Array<Float?> = Array(repeating: nil, count: 1000)
```

Comment: what the "repeating" means?

Comment: @BenShabat "repeating" keyword sets the same value for count elements

Answer (score 5):

Swift is a type-safe language. This essentially means that you can't store a value of some other type (here `nil`) in a variable/ constant of a particular type (here `Float`).

So, if you want to store nil values in an array, declare its element type as optional (here `Float?`).

```
var computeArray = [Float?](repeating: nil, count:1000)
```

or

```
var computeArray = Array<Float?>(repeating: nil, count:1000)
```