# About array in swift (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

how do I can set the size of an array? like `int *p_darr = new int[num]` in c++. I have a array of class and i want set data for my class in `for`. but i dont know how to set a size my array. `.append` not help me. I need a dynamic array of object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an array of certain size in Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46506430/how-to-make-an-array-of-certain-size-in-swift-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this array initializer in swift:

```
var array = [Int](repeating: 0, count: num)
```

This will create an array with zeros of `num` count. You can then access the elements of the array by index in a for loop like so:

```
for index in 0..<array.count {
    // Set here your new value
    let newValue = ...
    array[index] = newValue 
}
```

Comment: if i have a class ? i need a replace int on my class ? and in `repeating` do I also specify my class? i try it, but have equal data in all array

Comment: You can indeed use an array of your custom class too. The value you insert after `repeating` is the value that will be set for all items in the array. If you want to have different values you can set them when you loop over the array.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift arrays are dynamically sized. You don't have to pre-allocate your array to a given size. You can use code like this:

```
class Foo {
   //foo properties
}
let arraySize = 1000
var array: [Foo] = []
for _ in 1... arraySize {
   let aFoo = Foo()
   //configure aFoo
   array.append(aFoo)
}
```

Variable Arrays use an exponential allocation strategy where allocating space for extra elements is quite efficient. (Each time the array exceeds its previous size it doubles the amount of space used.) If you know how big your array is going to be, you can use the Array `reserveCapacity()` function to pre-allocate space for your array:

```
class Foo {
   //foo properties
}
let arraySize = 1000
var array: [Foo] = []

array.reserveCapacity(arraySize) //This is the extra line

for _ in 1... arraySize {
   let aFoo = Foo()
   //configure aFoo
   array.append(aFoo)
}
```

You could also use the array `init(repeating:count:)` initializer as mentioned by @silicon_valley